# Passing array to new page in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Just trying to receive an array on a new page using `Form.Navigate()`

First page:

```
private void Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] array = new string[] { var1, var2 };
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(secondpage), array);
}
```

Second page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    String[] array = (String[])e.Parameter;
}
```

No error, simply gives a null value

Comment: Is the NullReferenceException happening on the line `(String[])e.Parameter` where you're casting `e.Parameter`?

Comment: sorry it just gives a null value for the e.parameter. This is the array "array" sent from the first page right?

Comment: check String[] array instead of string[] array

Comment: try changing method name, Button is not good option

Comment: Get: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: when I try to use the array...

Comment: Have: string var1 { get; set; }
        string var2 { get; set; } outside of the method. Is that the problem?

Comment: Have you debuged your code? Have you put something to `var1`/`var2`?

Comment: string has default value null. if you try to access them you will get exception. do initialize var1/var2

Comment: String[] array = (String[])e.Parameter;
            var var3 = array[0]; <---error here

Comment: Can you add breakpoint at Frame.Navigate(typeof(secondpage), array); and check whether array is null or can you upload your sample?